# Selenium IDE storeText with elements having the same class

Tags: selenium, ide, selenium-ide

For example, how would you store the text of the following:

```
<div class="value">ABC</div>
<div class="value">123</div>
```

In the IDE I would have:
Command ::: Target : : : Value
storeText : : : ????? : : : Key1
storeText : : : ????? : : : Key2
I want to store the ABC as key1 and the 123 as Key2 so how do I make my target point to the correct element. Is there a way to index such as class=value[0] and class=value[1] to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use xpath for the Target:

```
Command   : : : Target                   : : : Value
storeText : : : //div[@class='value'][1] : : : Key1
storeText : : : //div[@class='value'][2] : : : Key2
```

The `[n]` is an index that will return the nth match.

Answer (score 0):

Also you could use 
storeText : : : //div[@class='value'][last()] : : : Key2

Please see following link for  details 
http://zvon.org/xxl/XPathTutorial/General/examples.html

Answer (score 0):

If you have fire bug add-on of the Firefox installed you can do the following:

1. Right click on the element and click on inspect element with Firebug and select the div or element that you want,
2. Right click on it and then click on Copy CSS path
3. In the your selenium plugin Target type "css=" after that paste the css path
4. now when you use the echo command next and run the test you should see the result. in the log section